# search a list in api/ format url seach for api

Tags: string, list, api, url, search

I want to generate 6 random numbers for pokemon api ID.
Put in list.
Then use the 6 numbers in url search.
The url doesn't recognise the list.
I need to convert the list to numbers. I'm not sure how to format them into the url.

```
import random
import requests

pokemon_ID = []

# pokemon_ID_add = str(pokemon_ID)[1:-1]
# pokemon_ID2 = str(pokemon_ID)[1:-1]


for i in range(0,6):
        number = random.randint(1 ,151)
        while i in pokemon_ID:
            number = random.randint(1, 151)
        pokemon_ID.append(number)




url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{}/'.format(pokemon_ID)
response = requests.get(url)
pokemon = response.json()

print(pokemon)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop to iterate over random IDs and store the result to a list:

```py
import json
import random
import requests

url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{}/"

random_pokemon_ids = [random.randint(1, 151) for i in range(6)]

result = []
for id_ in random_pokemon_ids:
    pokemon = requests.get(url.format(id_)).json()
    result.append(pokemon)

# pretty print the result:
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "abilities": [
            {
                "ability": {
                    "name": "rock-head",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/69/"
                },
                "is_hidden": false,
                "slot": 1
            },
            {
                "ability": {
                    "name": "lightning-rod",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/31/"
                },
                "is_hidden": false,
                "slot": 2
            },
            {
                "ability": {
                    "name": "battle-armor",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/4/"
                },
                "is_hidden": true,
                "slot": 3
            }
        ],
        "base_experience": 64,
        "forms": [
            {
                "name": "cubone",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/104/"
            }
        ],

...
```